# Difference between authentication and authorization filters in aspnet-mvc5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Why authentication filter is included in mvc 5? What is the major difference between authentication filter  and authorization filter  in mvc 5?

Answer (score 4):

I found the following blog post: [ASP.NET MVC 5 Authentication Filters](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/957/aspnet-mvc-authentication-filters)

Basically its about separation of concerns.

Authentication: find out WHO issued a request.

Authorization: find out whether a known user is allowed to perform a certain action.

Comment: Please include relevant content in your answer instead of simply linking to a blog post.

Answer (score 4):

To answer this you must understand the difference between *authentication* and *authorization*. Simply put,

- **Authentication** is the server trying to identify the user (i.e. asking the question of '**who are you**'). Usually this involves entering usernames, passwords, and/or access tokens.
- **Authorization** is the server determining whether the claimed user can/cannot perform certain actions.

Given the above definitions, authorization must come after authentication since you must be able to identify the user before determining what actions are legal for that particular user.

For ASP.NET MVC, authentication filters run **before** authorization filters as explained above. They both allow you the specify custom authentication (via `IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthentication` and `IAuthenticationFilter.OnAuthenticationChallenge`) and authorization logic (via `IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization`) respectively.

Comment: thanks for your answer.but can you give an example for how to implement forms authentication using  IAuthenticationFilter and IAuthorizationFilter