# Different Between AuthenticationFilter and AuthorizeFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can't understanding the difference between `AuthenticationFilter` and `AuthorizeFilter`. Could you please explain the main different and example about the `AuthenticationFilter` and `AuthorizeFilter`.

Comment: Possibly, this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264993/difference-between-authentication-and-authorization-filters-in-aspnet-mvc5

Answer (score 0):

in MVC.NET you can authenticate the user from forms mode in the web.config

`<authentication mode="Forms">`

So in this case the `AuthorizeFilter` `<Authorize>` will be used to verify if the user if logged in user or not.
*Now* for the `AuthenticationFilter` it controls the current user rights. what he should and shouldn't access.

the class Inherits `ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: This not true, 
The `AuthenticationFilter` is the one which Authenticates (see's if the user is logged in) while the `AuthorizeFilter` is the one which does the Access Rights

Comment: I don't want to confuse him but technically this is the tag that controls the login validation `<Authorize>` so you cannot say that my answer is not correct.

Answer (score -1):

Difference between Authentication and Authorization is

Suppose there is one Home/flat Authentication is used to check if you allow to enter in that Home or not 
and suppose there is multiple room in that flat so if you are allow to enter in that room or not we can check that using in Authorization

I hope you can understand by this

Comment: No, both are authorization. Authentication is showing your ID card to the receptionist and proving you are who you claim you are. Authorization is then checking whether you are allowed to enter either the building or specific rooms based on who you are.

Comment: yes @CodeCaster it is same but i have explain in simple forms

Comment: I did so in my first comment. Both of your examples are authentication. Authorization is something different.

Comment: No, process of explain for all is not same, please show me if i have something wrong explained

Comment: Authentication means confirming your own identity, whereas authorization means being allowed access to the system. -> i have explained this term in simple level is it not true ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. In your answer, you have dumbed down this explanation too much, making it incorrect. It doesn't matter which door (front door, apartment door, room door) you authenticate. A front door check doesn't suddenly make authentication authorization.

Comment: i have explained in simple level where beginner can understand , i think there is nothing wrong in terms of technical, and i don't find your excuse to devote my answer

Comment: No i have explained properly you have said that that is correct in your answer